# Problems with import on testing with JEST in React-Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, apollo

I have some problem.

In my React-Redux I try to test some file with action functions.
One of the function is async

Here is code of this file

```
import client from 'apollo/'
import { ME } from 'apollo/queries'

export const ActionTypes = {
  REQUEST_PROFILE: '@@profile/REQUEST_PROFILE',
  REQUEST_PROFILE_CANCELED: '@@profile/REQUEST_PROFILE_CANCELED',
  ERROR_REQUEST_PROFILE: '@@profile/ERROR_REQUEST_PROFILE',
} 

export const requestProfile = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.REQUEST_PROFILE })
  client.query({
    query: ME,
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
  }).then(resp => {
    const profile = resp.data.me
    dispatch(setUser(profile))
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log({...err})
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.ERROR_REQUEST_PROFILE, err })
  })
}
```

`import client from 'apollo/'` is an Apollo-client instance

Code of this file is simple too

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'
import { from } from 'apollo-link'
import { store }from '../redux/'
import { setErrorStatus } from 'actions/Base'
import { logOut, getToken } from 'helpers/localStorage'

const errorCodes = onError(({ networkError }) => {
  if (!networkError) {
    return false
  }
  let status = networkError.statusCode
  if (status === 400) {
    return false
  } if (status === 401) {
    logOut()
    return false
  }
  store.dispatch(setErrorStatus(status))
})

const cache = new InMemoryCache()
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = getToken()
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `JWT ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
})

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: `https://api.url.com/`,
})

export default new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorCodes, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache
})
```

`import { store } from '../redux/'` here I imported store, and at this file imported reducer.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import Profile from './Profile'


export default combineReducers({
    Profile
})
```

`import Profile from './Profile'`

```
import { ActionTypes } from 'actions/Profile'


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.REQUEST_PROFILE:
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Project working, on starting project no problems. In production env and in browser no errors too.

But when I try to test my `actions/Profile.js` there some strange error.

Here is code of test

```
import {
  requestProfile, ActionTypes
} from './Profile'

describe('Profile actions', () => {
  it('requestProfile', () => {

  })
})
```

And the error

````
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'REQUEST_PROFILE' of undefined

      16 | export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      17 |   switch (action.type) {
    > 18 |     case ActionTypes.REQUEST_PROFILE:
         |                               ^
      19 |       return state

      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.default (src/redux/reducers/Profile.js:18:31)
      at node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:53:24
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at assertReducerShape (node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:51:25)
      at combineReducers (node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:107:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/reducers/index.js:12:45)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/index.js:1:163)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/apollo-client/index.js:7:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/actions/Profile.js:1:174)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/actions/Profile.test.js:1:56)```

I cannot understand the core of this error. I am sure, that ActionType is here and it`s value not undefined. And `moduleNameMapper` is setup correctly. Any one can help me with this promlem?
````

Comment: Problem was with import file, that i testing

I had test `actions/Profile` and in nested imports this file was imported too

That was throw error

Answer (score 0):

`import { ActionTypes } from 'actions/Profile'` Is this the correct import?

Based on the rest of the code you've provided. Should the import not be:

`import { ActionTypes } from './Profile';`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, splitting your code is the best choice here in my experience. As you said, you were having an import error, generating a circular dependency when some files have async code, so the `{ types }` object was empty at the moment of the switch evaluation.
I solved it by moving `{ types }` to an independent file.